# Constructor parameter with byte, short and int throwing error

Tags: java, exception, types, constructor, constructor-overloading

I am trying to implement constructor overloading by using byte, short and long together. I am passing three values from main method and want to check which constructor gets called Test(byte, short, int) or Test(int, byte, short).

**CODE:**

```
import java.util.*;

public class Test {
    
    public Test(byte b, short s, int i) { //Line1
        System.out.println("b s i");
    }
    
    public Test(int i, byte b, short s) { //Line2 
        System.out.println("i b s");
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test ob = new Test(1, 2, 3); //showing compilation error //Line3
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems:
    The constructor Test(int, int, int) is undefined
```

Please tell me why its happening and what is the solution to this problem.

Comment: When you call the constructor you're passing values that are valid byte, int, shorts, so the compiler can't understand which actual constructor invoke. IIRC in java you can specify the type of primitives with something like long a = 1000L; or float f = 4.345f, can't remember for shorts and bytes thou. If all else fails, you can simply cast ;)

Comment: @BigMike there is no way to specify short or byte literals directly: casting is the only way. (Actually, you can specify e.g. `byte b = 1;`, without a cast: but that only works in variable declarations).

Comment: @AndyTurner aah that's why I didn't remember it ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default type of a whole number constant in Java is `int`. When you write `new Test(1, 2, 3)` you tell the compiler to looks for a constructor that takes three integers as parameters, which does not exist. That's exactly what the error message says.

You need to cast the parameters to explicitly define which constructor you want to call: `new Test(1, (byte) 2, (short) 3)`.